# WS02 GREG SCM Configuration to CVS

Tags: version-control, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying the below SCM configuration from Registry to connect to CVS server using the pserver method.

Below is the entry

```
<scm>
 <connection checkOutURL="scm:cvs:pserver:abcdef@myinfo.company.corp:9090/home/cvs:myproject/resource"
workingDir="/valid/filesystem/path" mountPoint="/_system/local/repository" checkInURL="" readOnly="true" updateFrequency="180">
        <username>abcdef</username>
        <password>XXXXXXX</password>
    </connection>
</scm>
```

working fine.

We want to have password less CVS configuration, an extssh method and when checkOutURL is modified accordingly, the Registry is asking for a Password to be entered on the startup.
Any idea regarding the SCM entry for password less CVS configuration.

If I use, ext protocol/method, are the username and password elements are required?

Answer (score 1):

Format the CVS url to mount to a CVS repository based on the following documentation
http://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html